# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol [C++] [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

I am using :

• VS2017

• Qt Designer

• MinGW

• Windows 10

• Qt 5.14.2

I get 4 LNK2019 errors when I include <QtNetwork/QNetworkInterface> in my code, but without it it builds just fine!
Here are the errors I am getting :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString __cdecl QNetworkInterface::hardwareAddress(void)const " (__imp_?hardwareAddress@QNetworkInterface@@QEBA?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MACAddress::on_loadButton_clicked(void)" (?on_loadButton_clicked@MACAddress@@AEAAXXZ)  MACAddress  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\C++ Projects\MACAddress\MACAddress\macaddress.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString __cdecl QNetworkInterface::humanReadableName(void)const " (__imp_?humanReadableName@QNetworkInterface@@QEBA?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MACAddress::on_loadButton_clicked(void)" (?on_loadButton_clicked@MACAddress@@AEAAXXZ)  MACAddress  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\C++ Projects\MACAddress\MACAddress\macaddress.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QNetworkInterface::QNetworkInterface(void)" (__imp_??0QNetworkInterface@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MACAddress::on_loadButton_clicked(void)" (?on_loadButton_clicked@MACAddress@@AEAAXXZ) MACAddress  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\C++ Projects\MACAddress\MACAddress\macaddress.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QNetworkInterface::~QNetworkInterface(void)" (__imp_??1QNetworkInterface@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MACAddress::on_loadButton_clicked(void)" (?on_loadButton_clicked@MACAddress@@AEAAXXZ)    MACAddress  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\C++ Projects\MACAddress\MACAddress\macaddress.obj    1
```

Comment: You probably did not add `QT += network` to your .pro file.\

Comment: @drescherjm I just added it, but I still get the same errors!

Comment: Probably need to run qmake then.

Comment: I resolve this issue by moving the project to Qt Creator instead of VS2017. I've read that this can happen because of a bug in VS.
Thank you @drescherjm !

Comment: Could be something with the addon. I develop my Qt applications in Visual Studio 2019 but I use CMake and not QMake + the addon. With this said CMake requires you to learn a lot of things to get this to work. I have used this at work since 2008.

Comment: Yes weird behavior, thank you @drescherjm for your help.